# how to install opencv4nodejs for windows 10

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm

I am not able to install opencv4nodejs
when I write npm install opencv4nodejs this gives a result

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\nikunj\Programming\testapp2\node_modules\opencv4nodejs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./install/install.js
npm ERR! info install using lib dir: D:/nikunj/Programming/testapp2/node_modules/opencv- 
build/opencv/build/lib/Release
npm ERR! D:\nikunj\Programming\testapp2\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\install\install.js:37
npm ERR!   throw new Error('library dir does not exist: ' + libDir)
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: library dir does not exist: D:/nikunj/Programming/testapp2/node_modules/opencv- 
 build/opencv/build/lib/Release
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\nikunj\Programming\testapp2\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\install\install.js:37:9)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\digital\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-25T06_54_47_181Z-debug.log`
```

Answer (score 1):

opencv4nodejs installation through auto build seems broken with Node.js current version (15.7.0). Until a possible fix, try with an earlier version of Node.js, 14.15.4 should work.

Answer (score 1):

opencv4nodejs dose not support to the current node version yet.
You can use nvm (Node Version Manager) to handle your node version.
You can switch your node version using nvm

If you switch to new version then run

```
npm rebuid
```

Inside your node package then it rebuild to the new version.

Comment: Probably meant `rebuild` (typo)

Answer (score 0):

To make it a complete answer, in order to install [opencv4nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv4nodejs) in Windows 10,

1. Install [CMake](https://cmake.org/download/)
2. Install windows build tools. `npm i -g windows-build-tools`.
3. Install opencv4nodejs. `npm install --save opencv4nodejs`

The following are the errors I encountered and the corresponding solutions.

1. In step 2, installing windows build tools, the installation takes forever to complete. Despite many debugging and trials, none is working and I fall back to use v4.0.0.
   `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0`
2. In step 3, installing opencv4nodejs, it throws the error library does not exists, similar with the question above. Consequently, downgrade to use node 14.15.4 solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Node.js version 14.15.4.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.